# Is it correct to say that precision is a parameter of a group of measurements while accuracy is a parameter of a SINGLE measurement?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, statistical-inference

I know that precision is how close are the obtained value of one another and accuracy is how close a value is to the REAL value that we seek.

Is it correct therefore to say that accuracy is a parameter of a single value, while precision is a parameter of a group of values?

Comment: An example: When I say that it is now 11:37 on 1 January 1900, this statement has minute *precision* but is *accurate* not even to the century. On the other hand, my paper calendar has only day precision, but it might have sub-second accuracy if I tear off its pages at midnight.

Comment: It is common in Bayesian statistics to define precision as the reciprocal of the variance. // More generally, _accuracy_ has to do with the mean and _precision_ with variability. In target practice: accuracy describes how well your shot cloud is centered on the bull's eye. Precision describes how small the shot cloud is. Tight shot cloud far from bull's eye is good precision, poor accuracy.